# Script to automatically set up my workspaces configuration upon login (Linux Mint 20.1)

Tags: bash, terminal, linux-mint, automation, bash-scripting

I am using Linux Mint 20.1 at the moment. My main work involves writing bash scripts for system monitoring. I am still new in this so I am learning on the job as we go.

Typically, upon logging in to my laptop, I would set up the various workspaces with the assigned apps for each workspace. I have in total 4 workspaces.

> > **Workspace 1** is the **Main workspace** where i only have Google Chrome open. I would have all the usual pages i refer to already pinned. Depending on the type of script i'm writing at that point in time, I would have multiple tabs open while i switches between workspaces 1,2 & 4.

> > **Workspace 2** is where i ***write and test my scripts***. I only have 2 terminals opened here. The first one on the left would be 155x55 and the 2nd terminal on the right would be 80x55. The left terminal is where i write my scripts using VIM while the right terminal are where i have the man pages etc running.

> > **Workspace 3** is usually blank. ***This is the ETC workspace.*** I would use this for any other thing that i dont already do in the other 3 workspace. Open documents, etc. I rarely use this workspace.

> > **Workspace 4** is where i ***have my QEMU/KVM running.*** I would open the Virtual Machine Manager where all my VMs would be listed, with the Host & CPU Usage graph is shown. This is on the left side of this workspace. To the right of VMM, I would have 2 terminals open, each at 110x55. The first terminal would usually be connected to the Main VM which is hosting some monitoring system while the other would be connected to my other VMs where the agents are configured.

Basically, my routine every morning is to power on this Mint laptop, login and then spend the next 10 mins or so setting up all these. after awhile, it's getting on my nerve, if i'm to be honest.  So i am thinking that maybe there's some script that i can set to run upon logging in to this laptop ? Or at least, something i can manually trigger but will automatically launch and setup the various workspaces accordingly ?

As I am new to this bash scripting thing, I would like to seek your advice and guidance on how to write this script. I have googled and read many FAQs and forums but i think since i have no idea what it would involve, probably i'm not using the right search terms ? I would appreciate if you could assist to point me in the right direction. I take this as another learning opportunity for me and look forward to upgrading my scripting knowledge and skills. :)

Comment: Just try it and come back if you face a problem that you cannot solve yourself. It is easy and you are unlikely to break something.

Comment: I don't even know where to start, to be honest. That's why i'm asking for direction here. What do i read up on ? What do I google with ?

Comment: 1. Find a way to reliably start all your applications. 2. find a way to move each application to its specific workspace, e.g. with [wmctrl](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=152602) 3. combine all that in a script 4. find a way to autostart that script after your desktop environment started, e.g. `~/.config/autostart` or `/etc/xdg/autostart`

Comment: Thanks for the info. I shall read up and try them out. Willreport back once i have it. :D

Comment: Good luck, just tag me with @mashuptwice if you have specific questions